# Sorting the Value of 2d-Array with Key-Value by column in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I want to sort following 2D-Array by column

**Unsorted:**

```
[('222801', '4470'), ('222802', '4753.5')], [('222811', '4468.5'), ('222812', '4742.5')]]
```

**Sorted:**

```
[('222811', '4468.5'), ('222812', '4742.5')], [('222801', '4470'), ('222802', '4753.5')]]
```

I think before, it must cast to Float of the values in the tuple.

I want to calculate the log10 and then the mean rowwise aftermath. so putting the results of the values as a replacement in the unsorted list 
Can anyone helps me?

For example
//Cast to Float then calculate log10

```
[(222811, log10(4468.5)), (222812, log10(4742.5))], [(222801, log10(4470)), (222802, log10(4753.5))]]
```

//Then calculate the mean by row

```
[(222811, log10(4468.5))+log10(4742.5)+log10(4470)+log10(4753.5)/len(arr), (222812, log10(4468.5)+log10(4742.5)+log10(4470)+log10(4753.5)/len(arr)], [(222801, log10(4468.5))+log10(4742.5)+log10(4470)+log10(4753.5)/len(arr), (222802, log10(4468.5))+log10(4742.5)+log10(4470)+log10(4753.5)/len(arr))]]
```

Comment: What is the idea behind that sort?

Comment: I want to calculate the log10 and then the mean aftermath. so putting the results of the values as a replacement in the unsorted list

Comment: I didn't get what you mean , can you explain it in that example?

Comment: AS appear in the example , the second item in all are same , what you should sort then?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by the first element of first tuple in the inner lists, you can implement something like this:

```
from math import log10

a1 = [[('222801', '4470'), ('222802', '4753.5')], [('222811', '4468.5'), ('222812', '4742.5')]]
mean = sum([log10(float(b)) for a in a1 for b in zip(*a)[1]])/2
mapped_a1 = [[(b[0][0],mean), (b[1][0],mean)] for b in a1]
sorted_a1 = sorted(mapped_a1, key=lambda x: x[0][0], reverse=True)
print sorted_a1
```

Output:

```
[[('222811', 7.326745061604671), ('222812', 7.326745061604671)], [('222801', 7.326745061604671), ('222802', 7.326745061604671)]]
```

Comment: How did you know that from question that he wants _sort by first element_?

Comment: so what about the `log10` thing?

Comment: @Arman Log can be calculated with map funciton. But the next step doesn't makes sense. He is adding float values to a tuple.

Comment: @MYGz It is with intention that it is with floaf. I meant, it must be casted to a float

Comment: @user3786117 This doesn't makes sense `(222811, log10(4468.5))+log10(4742.5)+log10(4470)+log10(4753.5)/len(arr)`. You are adding float values to a tuple and you haven't defined what `arr` is. Please take some time and edit your question.

Comment: @MYGz arr is the length of sub list. In this case 2

Comment: @MYG if my sublist length is 10 and list of 2d array is 100. it must be sorted_a1 = sorted(a1, key=lambda x: x[0][1], reverse=True), why

Comment: @user3786117 solve the mystery of adding float value to a tuple. Look closely here: `(222811, log10(4468.5))+log10(4742.5)`. You need to put the round brackets carefully to make sense. You have just tossed it here and there.

Comment: @MYGz: I mean i want to first calculate the log10 of each value. Second step is to calculate the mean of each row

Comment: @MYGz I want to replace the result of the values with same Key in matching to the unsorted originally array, so that results came to originally position. Can u help me?

Comment: @user3786117 `tuples` are immutable, you cannot change the values inside it.

Comment: What is a alternative solution?

Comment: @user3786117 I have zero clue what you are trying to do.

Comment: @user3786117 If you have got the average value correct, ask a separate precise question.

Comment: @MYGz It must be sorted before calculation, but it doesnt work. How must it look like be then?